# Creating extra columns in one table vs creating a new table with foreign key

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

I have a SQLite database with a table with 11 columns, including 8 columns as `Text` with very long strings. I need to add 8 more `Text` columns which may or may not get long string values.

So I'm wondering whether I should add those extra 8 columns to the current table or create a new table containing a foreign key?

Which way is better in case I want to use some queries to search data in my database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  If there are existing queries on this table, and if they do a "select *" to get all the columns, the query will change when the asterisc gets re-evaluated.  This might or might  not break the software that depends on the query.
There is a workaround for this, involving creating a new table with both the old columns and the new columns and then creating a view with the name and columns of the old table.  That workaround has a downside, too.

There are, as sadfiesch commented, no normalization issues here.

As far as performance goes, there are cases that go either way, and cases where it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the 8 more columns in the existing table. Try understanding the  [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you only add a new table if your database is redundant.